# Documentation for Word 2010 OLE on powerbuilder

Tags: ole, powerbuilder, word-2010

Powerbuilder application used Word 2003 so far, Now we have decided to move to Word 2010.But I couldn't find the proper documentation for Word OLE for powerbuilder.

Comment: Unless you hit a sliver of OLE functions that are incompatible between the two versions of Word, your existing code should work. Have you tried it yet? What specifically are you after?

Comment: Templates will simply have the bookmarks that will be replaced by the data.

Comment: OLE is pretty much OLE, but the documentation for the API is the responsibility of the OLE tool so you'd need to research Microsoft website for the Word OLE API functionality, then port the code to PB (which is easy if you already have a start).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced with accessing ole(mostly excel and one word ole) from Powerbuilder but I cannot post my code here because it is my company own ( event I built it).
I give you clue:

1. Create macro in Word.
2. See the code in VBA.
3. if there is constant var, please open vba browser to see original value , it can be numeric or int or string.
4. Look Powerbuilder documentation Ole ( connecttonewobject instead of connectoobject).
5. Create the code what ever you want, search in the internet Powerbuilder ole
6. close the connection   ole... quit (word ole) and  (destroy ole_name).

that's all, sorry cannot shared my code, that's from experience searching via Internet.